# XPath for text after a div?

Tags: html, xml, xpath, webharvest

How could I extract the number "-105" with XPath 1.0/2.0?

```
<td class="alignRight bookColumn" rel="page1" style="">
  <div id="_Div_Line_5_523714_901_3_119">-115</div>
  <div id="_Div_Line_5_523714_902_3_119">   
    <div class="oddsAlignMiddleOne">9.0</div>                        
    -105
  </div>
</td>
```

I tried with:

```
/td/div[2]/text()
```

Comment: Add some of your code to get better help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select `"-105"`, use the `following-sibling` axis:

```
normalize-space(/td/div[2]/div/following-sibling::text())
```